# Cookiebot throwing console errors in Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, requirejs, cookie, requirejs-config.js

I have added cookiebot script into head tag,

here is the script

```
<script id="Cookiebot" src="https://consent.cookiebot.com/uc.js" data-cbid="0000-0000-0000-0000" data-blockingmode="auto" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After adding this script, I am getting are many console errors,

> Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ( $ ) {

Tried contacting support, but could not succeed in that, please advise me how to resolve this error,

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Cookiebot can be a drama, but that depends mainly by your project customizations / plugins... I have seen lot of issues in M1 projects, but thankfully didn't have any in M2 (recently added it in a 2.3 with no issues). How are you including it in the head... Through backoffice or inside some template?

Comment: @RaulSanchez, I am including via backoffice, also tried with layout, but both are showing the same error

Comment: Which section? Head? or Footer?

Comment: Tried in both, head as well footer, same issue wherever we add

Comment: Can you provide online url to check console?

Comment: @RaulSanchez, please ping me your email id

Comment: raul.sanchez@somosinapsis.com ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a JS file here replacing VENDOR/THEME with your theme name - `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/web/js/cookiebot.js` and populate it with the below content:

```
require([
    'https://consent.cookiebot.com/uc.js?cbid=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
    'domReady!'
], function () {
    'use strict';
    console.log(Cookiebot);
});
```

2. Create `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Magento_Theme::js/cookiebot.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

3. Flush all caches

The network request to show it working:
[image]

The console warning because I do not have a key:
[image]

You can then access CookieBot with `Cookiebot`:

[image]

**The Cookiebot script loads and constructs a client-side JavaScript object named 'Cookiebot'** which exposes the public properties, methods, events and callback functions. For more info see their docs - https://www.cookiebot.com/en/developer/.

Comment: hi @Ben Crook, you mean i have to create new js file using requirejs?

Comment: @Manjunath Yeah, loading this outside of Require is the reason for your error.

Comment: hi @Ben Crook, possible to update me the steps to create the file please?

Comment: Sure, I have added those steps now @Manjunath

Comment: Thanks @Ben Crook, but i need small help, can we make enable/disable feature for this? like in admin we should able to control, as now we loaded from js, so its loading always unless we comment the lines.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use requirejs concept for including this file .

Can you use following link for the same ?

https://webkul.com/blog/call-configurable-external-js-url-magento2/

Comment: hi @Parul, I am not including any external js, got the script from cookiebot and tried to add before the body end, but getting the errors in console. I hope the above answer is not useful for me.

Comment: yes but you added script js file that generally not allowing to accept jqury and thats why it give such a error

Comment: I am not created any js file, just added that script inside the footer section, what is the solution to avoid that, can you please update me clearly, not getting from the suggested answer, I just need to add above script to get cookie pop up

Comment: can you check my second answer ?

Answer (score 1):

This line is worth a try:

```
<script src="https://consent.cookiebot.com/uc.js" id="Cookiebot" data-cbid="0000-0000-0000-0000" async defer></script>
```

then flush the cache
ensure you are in developer mode: php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

if you have doubts whether the cache was not flushed, do ensure the cookie line is present or not.

Comment: hi @Herve, same error after adding this code

Comment: Have you flushed the cache? I’ll be around in 1h30 and can dig properly then

Comment: yes i did cache flush, but still same error

Comment: hello @Herve did you ge time to check it?

Comment: yes, did not want to spoil the comments.. was keen to start a chat.. I have updated my answer too. Have you seen?

Comment: yes, i did cache flush, still same error in console, also my updated cookie line is present

Answer (score 0):

[image]Can you try in magento backend following thing ?

`Admin >> content >> design >> configuration >> Select Store >> html HEAD/Footer (Miscellaneous HTML`)

But this script will be displayed on all pages or else if you want to add on particular page than add following code in your layout xml file

```
    <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Namespace_Modulename::before.phtml" name="before_body_js"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

add template file before.phtml add below code

```
<script src="https://consent.cookiebot.com/uc.js" id="Cookiebot" data-cbid="0000-0000-0000-0000" async defer></script>
```

Comment: hi @Parul, yes i tried this. no change in it, still same error

Comment: https://support.cookiebot.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006093234-Magento-installation - see this blog same suggestion and even I tried too.

Comment: errors in console not removed, affecting on many features like slider, mega menu etc

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption:**

- You are using a Custom Magento Theme.
- You need the Cookiebot JS in all Frontend pages.

**(Step 1) Update  Entries**

If you already have a `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml` file in place - add the code-snippet shown below to it:

*Note:* If you don't already have a `default_head_blocks.xml` file in place - i.e. inside your Custom Theme - copy the file `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml` to the location `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/layout/` and then add the following entry to the end of it:

```
<link src="js/includes/Cookiebot.js"/>
```

**(Step 2) Create JS Payload File**

Create the File `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/web/js/includes/Cookiebot.js` with the following content:

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'https://consent.cookiebot.com/uc.js?cbid=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log(">>> CookieBot has been initialized ...");
    });
});
```

**Step 3) Clear Caches:**

Depending on the kind of caching-mechanisms you have deployed on your server (File/Varnish/Redis/etc) you may need to run some or all of these:

**Clear Magento-Caches:**

```
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento cache:clean
```

**Remove Cached-Files:**

```
# TO-DO: Please replace $MAGENTO_HOME/ - in the commands below - with the path to your Magento-Home-Folder on the server
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/var/cache/
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/var/page_cache/
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/var/session/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/generated/*
```

**Remove Static-Content:**

```
# TO-DO: Please replace $MAGENTO_HOME/ - in the commands below - with the path to your Magento-Home-Folder on the server
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/pub/static/frontend
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/pub/static/deployed_version.txt
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/pub/static/adminhtml
```

**Remove Cached Content in your Redis:**

```
# To Check if Redis is Running
sudo systemctl status redis.service ; 

# To Check Restart Redis
sudo systemctl restart redis.service ; 

# To Check if Redis is back up and running
# Hint: The PID in Previous and Current `Status` commands shoudl be different.
sudo systemctl -l status redis.service ;
```

**Remove Cached Content in your Varnish:**

```
# To Check if Varnish is Running on your Server
sudo systemctl status varnish.service ; 

# To Restart Redis on your Server
sudo systemctl restart varnish.service ; 

# To Check if Varnish is back up and running
# Hint: The PID in Previous and Current `Status` commands should be different.
sudo systemctl -l status varnish.service ;
```

**Step 4) Re-deploy**

Execute the following CLI Commands:

```
# IF you're running `Developer Mode` use the command below:
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --strategy standard

# IF you're running `Production Mode` use the command below:
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

# If you have `Developer Mode` Enabled - you shouldn't really need to run this. 
# But, if you're running `Production Mode` - you should do so.
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

**Step 5) Clear Your Browser Caches**

To avoid the possibility of Browser-Caching issues - please follow the Instructions specific to your Browser to clear It's Caches.

**Step 6) Test on Frontend**

Open a New Browser Window (Preferrably in Incognito-Mode) and go to your Magento Instances HomePage.

- *VALIDATION CRITERIA # 1:*

Check the Homepage's source code - i.e. on your Browser - for the following Code Snippet:

```
<link src="js/includes/Cookiebot.js"/>
```

- *VALIDATION CRITERIA # 2:*

Once the Homepage has finished loading - Check the Browsers Console for following Log message:

```
>>> CookieBot has been initialized ...
```

At this point, your Cookiebot snippet should be working as expected.

I hope this helps!

Cheers,

**Sharath**

Comment: can we handle it from admin side? instead of files

Comment: @Manjunath:

Please try this:

1. Login to Magento Admin Admin Panel -> Content > Design : Configuration.

2. Click on the "Edit" link of the Row that corresponds to the StoreView you want the head tag to be changed on OR Select Global if you need this change on EVERY StoreView.

3. Find the `HTML Head` section and add your JS code in the `Scripts and Style Sheets` field of that section/form

4. Once the desired changes have been made, click the `Save Configuration` button to commit these changes into the Database layer.

5. Flush Magento Cache(s).

6. Test on the Frontend.

Comment: hi @Sharath if editedd from admin section, there will be a console errors

Comment: @Manjunath Could you post screenshot / StackTrace of the error(s) you run into ?